# Animación lottifiles android studio

Tags: android-studio

[image: bueno eso es lo que hace, al iniciar ya se ve el loader, necesito que este oculto cuando inica, y caundo de click que inicie y luego se oculte]tengo un problema con animaciones de lottiefiles, el asunto es que se ve antes de cualquier click. Y despues se detiene pero no se oculta. Como puedo solucionar esto?

adjunto mi trabajo hasta aquí, muchas gracias de antemano ;)

```
 private LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    lottieAnimationView = findViewById(R.id.loaderlotti);
    lottieAnimationView.cancelAnimation();

 mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()){

                lottieAnimationView.cancelAnimation();

                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));

            }

            else {

                lottieAnimationView.cancelAnimation();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Creo que olvidaste el código

Comment: sí es verdad, disculpa.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno en realidad no pude resolver lo que tenía en mente, pero lo sustituí por algo que me gusta como quedó. Puse un archivo json de lottiefiles (el diseño es una mujer sentada, la animacón se basa en que ella mueve el pie.) entonces cuando doy clik en mi btn, ella acciona y en caso de que algo haya ido mal se detiene. Me parece agradable.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en el código lo que hice fue añadir los listeners

```
 lottieAnimationView.addAnimatorListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {



        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {


        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
```